# Order by order renormalization

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, feynman-diagrams, singularities

This post is a little bit related with my [last post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/754656/), where I don't totally understand one point. I think it's better to write a new post specialized for this point.

For a renormalized $\phi^4$ theory, (i.e., P&S's QFT, page 324) we can write the Lagrangian as
$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathcal{L}=\frac{1}{2} & \left(\partial_\mu \phi_r\right)^2-\frac{1}{2} m^2 \phi_r^2-\frac{\lambda}{4 !} \phi_r^4 \\
& +\frac{1}{2} \delta_Z\left(\partial_\mu \phi_r\right)^2-\frac{1}{2} \delta_m \phi_r^2-\frac{\delta_\lambda}{4 !} \phi_r^4 .
\end{aligned} \tag{10.18}
$$
where the first two terms are free part $\mathcal{L}_0$. The remaining six terms are interaction part $\mathcal{L}_{\text{int}}$. The second line are counterterms.

We can use generating function method to derive the feynman rule
$$Z[J]\sim e^{i\int d^4 x \mathcal{L}_{\text{int}}(\frac{\delta}{i\delta J})}e^{i\int d^4x(\mathcal{L}_0+J\phi)}. $$
And we can derive the Feynman rule of the last terms in (10.18) as

[image]

Later, I know that, we can use this $-i\delta_\lambda$ to absorb momentum independent divergences. In one-loop, it's of order $\mathcal{O}(\lambda^2)$; In two loop, it's of order $\mathcal{O}(\lambda^3)$. And they are independent. (See Qmechanic's answer in my last post!)

I am troubled for understanding above statements. How can we obtain this from the generating functions? In generating functions, we can only obtain some terms like $\mathcal{O}(\delta^2_\lambda)$, $\mathcal{O}(\delta^3_\lambda)$. How can this counter term related with $\mathcal{O}(\lambda^2)$ and further independent? This counterterm always in tree level?

I am appreciate you have any comments!

Comment: What makes you believe that the generating functional does not generate a term of $\mathcal{O}(\delta_\lambda)$? Just write down the relevant term in $\mathcal{L}_{\rm int}(\delta/i\delta J)$ and convince yourselve.

Comment: @Hyperon Yes, I believe that I can generate a term of $\mathcal{O}(\delta_\lambda)$. But the thing is, when P & S discussion the renormalization in one loop order (Page 326) and two loop order(Page 326), the book seems to use the same $-i\delta_\lambda$. Could you please comment more about this?

Comment: Peskin-Schroeder determine $\delta_\lambda$  order by order in the loop expansion by employing the renormalization condition (10.19). They perform the one-loop calculation explicitly, obtaining $\delta_\lambda = c_2 \lambda^2 +\mathcal{O}(\lambda^3)$ (c.f. 10.22). The terms of higher $\mathcal{O}(\lambda^3)$ remain, of course, still undetermined at one-loop order.  Their determination requires a two-loop calculation of the amputated 4-piont function, giving $\delta_\lambda =c_2 \lambda^2 +c_3 \lambda^3 +\mathcal{O}(\lambda^4)$, etc., etc. (see also the remark by P.-S. after (10.22.)).

Comment: @Hyperon Great! Thank you very much, that's make sense. May I comment further to make sure I totally understand? It's enough if we only use the tree-level $-i\delta_\lambda$ counterterm to absorb momentum independent divergence. However, we can expand $\delta_\lambda=c_2\lambda^2+c_3\lambda^3+\mathcal{O}(\lambda^3)$, etc., and $c_2,\ c_3$ are independent. To each order, we can freely adjust $c_2,\ c_3$, etc., to absorb the divergence. Would this right, thanks!